# How to login to self service from External site

Tags: customer-portal

I know you can login to the self service portal by passing the username and password through the URL:

`https://login.salesforce.com/sserv/login.jsp?orgId=<orgId>&un=<username>&pw=<password>`

However I would like to find a way to do this without passing this information via the query string. Is there a way to validate the user via an API, then pass a security token, or maybe Session ID to the URL instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of [How to Implement Single Sign-On with Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com). In particular, the section on the Sample SOAP Message to get the session Id.

Then take the valid Session ID and combine it with frontdoor.jsp. It will be something like:

> https://[podInstance].salesforce.com/sserv/frontdoor.jsp?sid=[sessionid]